# Flutter | ERROR | database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location

Tags: xcode, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

**Full error message**

```
Error (Xcode): unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database "/Users/eapple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gvpltuxpqwltadakkxbfdszjoppl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/build.db": database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just closed the emulator then removed it from dock and finally stated it again and all of the sudden everything was working fine error had just vanished.

Comment: For real device also, this worked.  unplug and plug. Then i tried to run in xcode first. For that do Product ->  'clean build folder' in xcode, then run.